# Load data from Firestore on page load with useEffect

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, next.js

Simplified code that I am using:

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { firestore } from './firebase-config'
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default function HomePage() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const user = useContext(AuthContext) // contains user object -> user.user 

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async() => {
      setLoading(true)
      const uid = user.user.uid // uid of user in firebase auth
      const id = router.query.id // id param of url

      const docRef = doc(firestore, `...`) 
      // doc in a collection that references the above uid and id
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
      // get the document from firestore

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        importData(docSnap.data()) // add data to store to re-render page
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        router.push('/main') 
        // if the user isn't logged in to return to '/'
          // ^^ not sure how to do these separately
        // if the user is logged in but the document does not exist to return to '/main'
      }
    }
    getData()
  }, [router.query, user.user])

  return (
    <>
      {/*  */}
    </>
  )
}
```

I need to load the document associated with the user's `uid` and the `id` param of the currently loaded page, i.e. `/main/[id]`.
These retrieve a Firestore document that is then inserted into the store which causes the HomePage function to re-render to show the data.

`uid` is found in `user.user.uid` which is set via `onAuthStateChanged` in `app.js`

`id` is found in `router.query.id` which is set via `useRouter()` at the top level

The `useEffect()` above works, but only temporarily, soon after the data is loaded and the component re-renders, I am linked to `'/main'` as initially `uid` and `id` start as `undefined` meaning that on the first run of the `useEffect` hook the `else` condition is run, it then re-runs as the `user` and `router` object is retrieved to load the data, but by the time that has occurred the page is transitioned to `'./main'`.

Would greatly appreciate some help to make this function work.

Additionally, the user should go back to `'./main'` if the document doesn't exist but they are logged in, and if they are not logged in to then be returned to the root (`'./'`)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a loading state for the document retrieval in addition to the loading state that you already have to make sure that the document retrieval is completed before navigating away from the page.

```
import { firestore } from './firebase-config'
import { getDoc, doc } from 'firebase/firestore'

export default function HomePage() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const user = useContext(AuthContext) // contains user object -> user.user 

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [docLoading, setDocLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async() => {
      setLoading(true)
      const uid = user.user.uid // uid of user in firebase auth
      const id = router.query.id // id param of url

      if (!uid) {
        setLoading(false)
        router.push('/')
        return
      }

      if (!id) {
        setLoading(false)
        router.push('/main')
        return
      }

      const docRef = doc(firestore, `...`) 
      // doc in a collection that references the above uid and id
      setDocLoading(true)
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
      // get the document from firestore
      setDocLoading(false)

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        importData(docSnap.data()) // add data to store to re-render page
        setLoading(false)
      } else {
        router.push('/main')
      }
    }
    getData()
  }, [router.query, user.user])

  if (loading || docLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* render your component here */}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have managed to fix the issue using your example, see my separate post.

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to fix the issue:

To be able to use `uid` in the `useEffect()` hook, `onAuthStateChanged` is called again rather than using the `AuthContext` that is created at the top level as this will wait until the user exists

To wait for `router.query` to be updated you can call `router.isReady` which returns a `Boolean` value on whether it has been updated.

Using both of these in this way:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      if (router.isReady) {
        // do stuff -> user exists
      } else {
        // user exists but the document does not 
        router.push('/main')
      }
    }
    else {
      // user is not logged in 
      router.push('/')
    }
  })
}, [router.isReady, router.query])
```